# Sitecore User Group - Brisbane, Australia - December 11, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Personalisation Workshop, Sitecore Pub Quiz and Christmas Drinks**

Join us for a bit of interactive fun for the last meetup for 2018.

Greg Baxter will run a short interactive group workshop to brainstorm getting started with personalisation. Something every Marketer wants to do.

After that, we'll run a Sitecore Pub Quiz - how good is your Sitecore knowledge?

Plenty of prizes on the night.

To finish off, we'll of course have some Christmas drinks to celebrate a great 2018. In fact, you can enjoy a drink anytime throughout the night.

**When (Local):** Tuesday, December 11, 2018, 6:00 PM

**When (UTC):** Tuesday, December 11, 2018, 8:00 AM

**Where:** Speedwell House, 105 Brunswick St, Fortitude Valley

[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-Brisbane-User-Group/events/256432119/)

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Dec 2 at 22:00